# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'/

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

Whenever I try run this code, it displays:

```
 AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

The first line returns the error:

```
result = str(model.predict_classes(roi, 1, verbose = 0)[0])
cv2.putText(copy, getLetter(result), (300 , 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('frame', copy)
```

Comment: `model.predict_classes` is no longer exists in recent versions. Instead use `preds=model.predict` and then `np.argmax(preds)`.

Comment: Could you please provide this in context to my code. So I could integrate it into my code

Comment: Hi, ace. Please mention the library the error relates to (cv2 in this case) in the title of your question so members can find it in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the `model.predict_classes()` has been deprecated. If you use Jupyter Notebook and Tensorflow 2.5.0, you would get a warning like the following:

> C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu-2.5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:455: UserWarning: `model.predict_classes()` is deprecated and will be removed after 2021-01->01. Please use instead:* `np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`,   if your >model does multi-class classification   (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last->layer activation).* `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`,   if your >model does binary classification   (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer >activation).
> warnings.warn('`model.predict_classes()` is deprecated and '

As the warning suggest, please use instead:

- `np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`, if your model does multi-class classification (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last-layer activation).
- `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`, if your model does binary
  classification (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).

I just upgraded to Tensorflow 2.6.0 with Python 3.9.6, in TF 2.6.0 using `model.predict_classes()` will straight up showing error.

```py
predict = NN.predict_classes(X_test_NL)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f1898c8da755> in <module>
----> 1 predict = NN.predict_classes(X_test_NL)

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

If you must use `predict_classes()`, you would have to roll back to previous version of tensorflow.

Or convert the probabilities you get from using `.predict()` to class labels.

References: [Get Class Labels from predict method in Keras](https://androidkt.com/get-class-labels-from-predict-method-in-keras/)

Comment: Please do not share codes as images. Always put codes as text.

Comment: @Kaveh Oops, forgot to crop only the error message. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: thank you for this helpful answer to the question but the point still applies: replace those images with *the text they contain*.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I honestly don't know that the error messages or any traceback messages have to be formatted. Thanks for letting me know. Editing it.

Comment: the idea is that this makes the post *searchable/findable*, i.e. *valuable*. otherwise you'd rely on search engines applying OCR, which is a waste of time (and error-prone, if done at all!), if instead you could just post the text in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This function was removed in TensorFlow version 2.6. According to the keras in rstudio reference

update to

```
predict_x=model.predict(X_test) 
classes_x=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)
```

The answer is from https://stackoverflow.com/users/13094270/xueke